# How to send query params as query string?

Tags: php, redirect, uri

I have this scenario. I am implementing payment for my application and url is like `http://example.com/payment?referenceId=123`. And before that I need to check for authentication and need to use `redirect_url` concept if the user is not logged in. I have this url for redirect_url: `http://example.com/login?redirect_url=URL`
Since I have query parameters in source url too, I couldn't use that url as redirect_url. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you explain little bit about  "Since I have query parameters in source url too, I couldn't use that url as redirect_url. How can I do this?"

Comment: In source url I have this query param: `referenceId=123`. If I put all together it is coming like `http://example.com/login?redirect_url=http://example.com/payment?referenceId=123`. And if we access that we are losing referenceId and browser redirecting it to `http://example.com/login?redirect_url=http://example.com/payment`. But I need referenceId too

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to do this task is to store http://example.com/payment?referenceId=123 in session when redirecting to login page and when login is completed then check if session has value for redirect then redirect to that url from session.

Answer (score 0):

To check authentication store referenceId as a session variable. Start session in your authentication page and check the url-referenceId is equal to the stored userId of that particular session.

```
session_start(); 

$_SESSION['referenceId'] = 123; 

if((url_ReferenceId)=$_SESSION['referenceId'])
{

//Check for authentication
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For URL http://example.com/login?redirect_url=http://example.com/payment?referenceId=12‌​3

Use   `$redirect_url = $_GET['redirect_url'];`
 // $redirect_url contains http://example.com/payment?referenceId=12‌​3

Then use php's inbuild function parse_url to filter out '`referenceId`' from `$redirect_url`

```
<?php
$url = '//www.example.com/path?googleguy=googley';

var_dump(parse_url($url));
?>

array(3) {
  ["host"]=>
  string(15) "www.example.com"
  ["path"]=>
  string(5) "/path"
  ["query"]=>
  string(17) "googleguy=googley"
}
```

Check for more info  `http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php`

This part `googleguy=googley` will actually hold your required data